# CakePHP validation on => 'create', on => 'update'

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm hoping you cakephp experts can answer this re Cake 2.1 and data validation in the model.

Cake gives you an "on" key for use in the validate array. I understand what the docs say about this but my question is, what's the point of these two items.

Let's say I have a validation rule for when a record is created. The validation passes and the record is created.

Then the user goes and edits that record and changes it to something that no longer passes that particular validation. But since I've got my validation set to run on create only, the validation passes and the record is updated with invalid data. It seems to me like this would apply to any on create / on update rules. If a user wanted to bypass validation, just create a valid record, then go and edit it so it's now invalid.

Can someone perhaps help me understand when it might make sense to use on update and on create?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is most useful in conduction with the `required` rule. You should set certain fields that are minimally required to be `required` `'on' => 'create'`. This makes the rule fail if those fields don't exist in the data set and the record cannot be created, but allows you to update existing records without having to pass that field each and every time.

For example:

```
'email' => array(
    'required' => array(
        'on'         => 'create',
        'rule'       => 'notEmpty',
        'message'    => 'Enter your email address',
        'required'   => true,
        'last'       => true
    ),
    'notempty' => array(
        'rule'       => 'notEmpty',
        'message'    => 'Enter your email address',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'last'       => true
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule'       => 'email',
        'message'    => 'Not a valid email address',
        'last'       => true
    )
)
```

Comment: Great that answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found it really useful in cooperation with profile pictures. You need one to be uploaded on create (if it is needed), but on update i can remain empty => no update to picture will be done.

Answer (score 0):

`'on' => null` will do the job

**EDIT :**

Ok, let's say you have a Profile model.

If you have a Date of Birth field, you would probably use a rule that would be enforced for both addition and edition.

You might also add a delete_picture checkbox in your form that a user should select in order to delete their profile picture. When adding, you have no profile picture so this field is only relevant at edition time and you would then use on => update.

Let's say you also have a group field that is set when you create the object but that is meant to never be changed. You would then use on => create.

Comment: Won't that just run the validation on update & create? My question is more toward when to use update vs create and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Definitely gives me something to work with. I'd upvote but I'm too noobish.